# What is known about sets $f(x_1,...x_n)=0$ and what theory investigates them?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, reference-request

Suppose that $f(x_1,...x_n)$ is a polynomial of $n$ real variables with real coefficients of degree $m$ and that we investigate sets $f(x_1,...x_n)=0$.

I would like to know what is generally known about such sets (depending on the number of variables and degree)?

What theory deals with questions like these? What to read and where?

Comment: This sounds like real algebraic geometry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_algebraic_geometry

Comment: @coreyman317 Sounds good! :)